# Review Won't Show Up

Tags: ios-appstore, app-store-connect

So, I wrote a review for an app. Both positive and negative thoughts in it, then I refreshed it and its not there. Help? Do I need a review account because all the people who review have some kind of username.

Answer (score 3):

Reviews on the Mac App Store and iOS App Store will **never** show up right away. Reviews are first reviewed, to avoid spam comments and reviews with offensive material.

Your review will show up once it is reviewed and approved (assuming your review is free of offensive language and is not spam or some other nonsense).

Bear in mind, too, that reviewing an App which you downloaded by redeeming a promo code is not possible. The systems lets you proceed with the review process althought the review will never appear nor the rating taken into account.

Comment: Bear in mind, too, that reviewing an App which you downloaded by redeeming a promo code is not possible. The systems lets you proceed with the review process althought the review will never appear nor the rating taken into account.

Comment: @Thecafremo Why would they even allow a review if it is not taken into account, then (in that case)?

Comment: "When a customer downloads an app using a promo code, the app behaves just as it would if it had been purchased. For example, the customer has the opportunity to update to new versions of the app. However, customers aren’t able to rate or review an app that was downloaded using an iTunes Connect promo code." from https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ProvidingPromoCodes.html